# Jcombobox in jTable dropdown arrow visibility question

Tags: jtable, jcombobox

I am having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to keep the drop-down arrow of my jcombobox (which is contained in a cell of a jTable) visible at all times.  I know this is possible because in the gui-builder properties panel table there are many comboboxes with this property.  The point of doing this is to make it obvious to users of my table that they have options in this cell of the table.  I do not want it to appear as just another text cell.

Could you please provide me with some direction?

Comment: Have you tried extending [TableCellRenderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) to work with JComboBoxes?